# How to track Authorize.Net Point Of Sale Transactions using EMV card reader

Tags: webhooks, authorize.net, emv, pos

How can we track the Authorize.Net Point Of Sale Transactions using EMV card reader. Does it support any webhook functionality feature?

I need to get below details

1. Invoice number
2. Purchase order ID
3. Paid amount
4. Customer ID

Answer (score 0):

A Webhook occurs regardless of the origin of the payment. So payments made by EMV card readers will have a webhook associated with them.

But, all of the detail you are looking for will *not* be in the webhook itself. The webhook will let your system know about the transaction and include a transaction ID. You can then use that transaction ID with their [Transaction Reporting API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/transaction_reporting.html) to retrieve any information associated with that transaction.

Looking at the the Transaction Detail response, I do see a field for Invoice Number but not PO Number or Customer ID. If your system can send over a transaction description you can put them into the Description field. Otherwise you will need to track this information on your side.

The call would be `getTransactionDetailsRequest` and would look similar to:

```
{
   "getTransactionDetailsRequest":{
      "merchantAuthentication":{
         "name":"",
         "transactionKey":""
      },
      "transId":"2162566217"
   }
}
```

With a response of

```
{
   "transaction":{
      "transId":"2162566217",
      "submitTimeUTC":"2011-09-01T16:30:49.39Z",
      "submitTimeLocal":"2011-09-01T10:30:49.39",
      "transactionType":"authCaptureTransaction",
      "transactionStatus":"settledSuccessfully",
      "responseCode":1,
      "responseReasonCode":1,
      "responseReasonDescription":"Approval",
      "authCode":"JPG9DJ",
      "AVSResponse":"Y",
      "batch":{
         "batchId":"1221577",
         "settlementTimeUTC":"2011-09-01T16:38:54.52Z",
         "settlementTimeUTCSpecified":true,
         "settlementTimeLocal":"2011-09-01T10:38:54.52",
         "settlementTimeLocalSpecified":true,
         "settlementState":"settledSuccessfully"
      },
      "order":{
         "invoiceNumber":"60",
         "description":"Auto-charge for Invoice #60"
      },
      "requestedAmountSpecified":false,
      "authAmount":1018.88,
      "settleAmount":1018.88,
      "prepaidBalanceRemainingSpecified":false,
      "taxExempt":false,
      "taxExemptSpecified":true,
      "payment":{
         "creditCard":{
            "cardNumber":"XXXX4444",
            "expirationDate":"XXXX",
            "cardType":"MasterCard"
         }
      },
      "customer":{
         "typeSpecified":false,
         "id":"4"
      },
      "billTo":{
         "phoneNumber":"(619) 274-0494",
         "firstName":"Matteo",
         "lastName":"Bignotti",
         "address":"625 Broadway\nSuite 1025",
         "city":"San Diego",
         "state":"CA",
         "zip":"92101",
         "country":"United States"
      },
      "recurringBilling":false,
      "recurringBillingSpecified":true,
      "product":"Card Not Present",
      "marketType":"eCommerce"
   },
   "messages":{
      "resultCode":"Ok",
      "message":[
         {
            "code":"I00001",
            "text":"Successful."
         }
      ]
   }
}
```